# How do I change a basic disk to dynamic one?

Tags: windows-7, windows

How can I change my C: basic drive into a dynamic drive? I want to make a new drive for storing data.

Comment: Did you research this at all? It's an extremely common result [on Google](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=change+basic+disk+to+dynamic). We expect people to do some basic research before posting questions. Follow the many available guides and let us know when you get stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft provides documentation for this (the caveats may apply to you):

- [Change a Basic Disk into a Dynamic Disk](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731274.aspx)

  > Do not convert disks to dynamic that contain multiple installations of Windows 2000, Windows XP Professional, or the Windows Server 2003 family of operating systems.
  >
  > If you do not see this menu item, you might be right-clicking a volume instead of a disk, the disk might have been previously converted to a dynamic disk, or the computer is a portable computer. (Dynamic disks are not supported on portable computers, removable disks, detachable disks that use Universal Serial Bus (USB) or IEEE 1394 (also called FireWire) interfaces, or on disks connected to shared SCSI buses.) In addition, you cannot convert cluster disks connected to shared SCSI or Fibre Channel buses to dynamic disks. The Cluster service supports basic disks only.)
- [Basic and Dynamic Disks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363785%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

  > You can use both basic and dynamic disks on the same computer. The catch is that volume sets must use the same disk type.
- [Working with Basic and Dynamic Disks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd163552.aspx)

  > You can use both basic and dynamic disks on the same computer. The catch is that volume sets must use the same disk type. For example, if you have mirrored drives C and D that were created under Windows NT 4.0, you can use these drives under Windows Server 2008. If you want to convert C to the dynamic disk type, you must also convert D.